# Chat server - can't receive message while getting input from user

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, networking

Okay so I understood what I did wrong. But I have another problem now, where using multithreading doesn't work as intended. In the code below, in the main fucntion, I start the message_listener thread, which should work in the background while I get user input. But when I send something from another client, the message doesn't get printed (and it should) in the other client's terminal. Not even after the receiver client send a message himself. I dont understand what I got wrong.

```
import socket
import sys
import threading
from datetime import datetime
import errno
import msvcrt
HEADER_LENGTH = 10

HOST = "127.0.0.1"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 50000  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("127.0.0.1", PORT))
client.setblocking(False)

username = input("Choose a username: ")
username_header = f"{len(username.encode()):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode()
client.send(username_header + username.encode())


def client_input(u_name):
    print(f"{u_name}>", end="")
    msg = ""
    done = False
    while not done:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            pressed = msvcrt.getch()
            if pressed == b"\r":
                print("")
                done = True
            else:
                print(pressed.decode(), end="")
                msg += pressed.decode()
    return msg


def message_handler():
    while True:
        try:
            uname_header = client.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)

            if not len(uname_header):
                print('Connection closed by the server')
                sys.exit()

            # actual username
            sender_username_length = int(uname_header.decode().strip())
            sender_username = client.recv(sender_username_length).decode()

            sender_message_header = client.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)
            sender_message_length = int(sender_message_header.decode().strip())
            sender_msg = client.recv(sender_message_length).decode()

            now = datetime.now()
            current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print(f"<{current_time}> {sender_username}: {sender_msg}")

        except IOError as error:
            if error.errno != errno.EAGAIN and error.errno != errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                print(f"There was some error reading data: {str(error)}")
                sys.exit()

            # no data was received (everything's fine)
            return
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"There was some error reading data: {str(error)}")
            sys.exit()


def main():
    msg_listener = threading.Thread(target=message_handler)
    msg_listener.start()

    while True:

        message = client_input(username)

        # if message is not empty, send it.
        if message:
            # Encode message to bytes, prepare header and convert to bytes, like for username above, then send
            message = message.encode()
            message_header = f"{len(message):<{HEADER_LENGTH}}".encode()
            client.send(message_header + message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It seems like the message_handler doesn't receive anything... Because if for example, I put a print statement after the `uname_header = client.recv(HEADER_LENGTH)` line , it doesn't get printed. So it means the thread isn't working in the background? i dont get it.

For some reason, after one iteration over the while True loop in the main function, the msg_listener thread stops. Why does it stop tho? it has a while True loop in it!

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You said, "I've tried turning the `client_input` function to a Thread. It didn't work." OK, so, you already understand what's wrong with the code in your example—`client_input` doesn't return until the user types something. It sounds like the thing you _don't_ understand is why your multi-threaded version "didn't work." So, show us the multi-threaded version. Maybe say a little more about what "didn't work" means, and then maybe somebody can show you what you did wrong.

Comment: For some reason, after one iteration over the while True loop in the main function, the msg_listener thread stops. Why does it stop tho? it has a while True loop in it!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I see that your `message_handler` function will return (and the thread ends) _without printing any diagnostic message_ if an `IOError` other than `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` is thrown.

Comment: Oh damn. i actually didnt notice and there as the error. It said "a non blocking socket could not be completed immediatly". So i removed the `setBlocking` at the beggining (i didnt really understand what it does anyway). I probably didnt need it cause i implemented the non blocking feature myself with the threads?  anyways, huge thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because the program waits for input from the user before receiving new messages. Your actions do not work in parallel.

I suggest making the following changes

```
import threading


def message_handler():
    while True:
        # open listening and print new msg
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    msg_listener = threading.Thread(target=message_handler)
    msg_listener.start()

    while True:
        message = client_input(username)
        # send msg
```

In this case, you will always listen to messages in the background. And in the main thread to process user input

Comment: Okay I did what u said. But now in the message handler, for some reason, it doesn't recv anything (when sending message from another client, therefore it doesn't print the message at all, not even after the client sends a message (which worked before)) should i update the question to include the new code?

Comment: My example is meant to give you the right idea about how it should work. Instead of `threading`, you can use `async/await`. 
Hope this helps you
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html